# How to restrict Linux find by prefix?

Tags: linux, find

I have a directory `A` with a large number of sub directories and files and want to get a list of all files named `foo` that are inside of a directory in `A` that matches `*bar`. E.g.:

- Yes: `./goldbar/fiz/baz/foo`
- Yes: `./leadbar/foo`
- No:  `./candy/figbar/foo`

I have the some additional constraints:

- I must not descend into directories that don't match the `*bar` (this is a necessary optimization as it would take to long to scan those)
- I can't allow the shell to do the glob expansion because it returns to many results: (i.e. `find *bar -type f -name foo` fails)

---

I think that the [`-path` flag](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) would give me the results I need but I don't know if it fits the first of the above constraints.

---

Edit: Assume that there are n*10k directories in `A` that match `*bar`. i.e. anything that tries to build a command with all of them (as opposed to handling each one in tern) will fail.

Comment: What Unix are you using? Each one has their own oddities in find. If you're using Linux, you'll have GNU find, which includes the -prune option which is possibly the right route to go down

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how `-path` will handle the "do not descend into directories that don't match `*bar`" requirement, and I'm too lazy to build an environment to find out.
I do know the following will work on pretty much any *nix platform:

```
for dir in `ls -1 | grep bar`; do
   find $dir -type f -name foo
done
```

Additional weaseling of the `ls`/`grep` bit may be required if you have plain files, sockets, etc. in your top-level directory, or if you want to revise your conditions a little.

Comment: As I understand it, that will expand to `for dir in <some long list of dirs>;` and unless bash handles it as a stream, it can be expected to fail. (See edit)

Comment: The "expansion" here is actually handled by `ls` & `grep` -- the shell just gets a really long list to process (which can chew up RAM, but shouldn't fail) -- for example `for f in \`find /usr\`; do echo $f; done | wc -l` processed around 371,000 items on my box, no problem :-)

Comment: If you're worried about shell limits, you can always do something like `ls -1 | grep bar$ | while read dir; do ... done`.

Comment: 1) So for is not subject to command line length limits? 2) memory pressure is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a solution purely with `find`, then

```
find . \( -depth 1 -type d \! -name "*bar" \) -prune -o \( -depth +1 \! -type d -name foo \) -print
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I get `warning: you have specified the -depth option after a non-option argument (, but options are not positional (-depth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it)` in GNU find, you can only tell it to work at one depth or the other.

Comment: Ah, that's right. GNU find and BSD find argue about `-depth`. I don't see a good GNU find solution with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Try this - not sure how quick it will be though.

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*bar' -exec find {} -name foo \;
```

NOTE this doesn't work for Solaris 10 as it's find doesn't have `-maxdepth`

Comment: I'm fairly sure that would do what I want, but even the first find is to slow: i.e. I have other problems. :(

Comment: @BCS:It works on the data you provided. You're not going to find anything that does this quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I checked with strace and -path by itself does not avoid the unneded incursion into non-matched directories. This should do the job, though:

`find .  \( -name '.' \) -print -o \( ! -path '*directory_pattern*' \) -prune -o -name '*file_pattern*' -print`

The `\(` and `\)`s aren't actually needed on this particular case, but they add readability and would probably be needed if you used more complex expressions. Checked with strace and it seems to work, hope it helps.

Comment: Looks like a good solution if your version of `find` has the -prune option, but it seems to rely on having a "pattern to exclude" - that could be a long pattern/list of patterns

Comment: Fixed that, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

How about a regex version:

```
find -regex './[^/]*bar/.*/?foo$'
```

EDIT: Tweaked it with a cleaner one and terminating the line (so you're not matching fooble, foogasm, etc...)

Comment: This works, but strace shows `find` thinks it's necessary to `stat` all directories and subdirectories, so I'm not sure it's optimizing as well as it should. But perhaps it's fast enough for @BCS.

Comment: @Eduardo: If it's looking at extra subdirs, it is most definitively NOT fast enough.

Comment: Good point. It'll have to stat every directory to match the regex against them.